# How to improve default execution speed in Xilinx ISE?

Tags: verilog, xilinx-ise

I was trying to implement a 1Hz clock using 100MHz clock.
However, In the xilinx ISE, ISIM execution speed is around 5ms per second.
This is too slow for my project.
How do I modify default execution speed?

Comment: Normally one does not simulate a second. Most designs have a SIM_SPEEDUP generic to reduce cycles or time in simulation. There is no gain for waiting 100,000,000 cycles than just waiting for 100 cycles.

Answer (score 0):

Have you purchase a full ISE license? It's said that iSim is faster in the unlocked version ...

You could use an alternative simulator:

- ModelSim / QuestaSim
- GHDL